# Стресс сайта на 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом

Tags: битрикс, ddos

Читал про защиту, что стрессерами не берет, читал про лаги, когда на сайте человек 100. Получается, что сайт можно положить активными пользователями, но не стрессером? Или я не особо понимаю принципы их защиты?

Answer (score 1):

авторизованные пользователи на то и авторизованные, что могут создать нагрузку на сервер значительно большую, нежели анонимы: сервер просто обязан предоставлять им право нагружать себя *такими* задачами, которые просто не позволит выполнить неавторизованным пользователям.

это общее соображение, без какой-либо конкретики, будь то «один эс», «два дэ» или «три тэ».